# Dojo widget is not working properly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, dojo

I am using jQuery and Dojo widget on same JSP page but getting this issue,

Dojo part is working fine until I click on jquery based dropdown, as soon as I click jQuery-Dropdown, dojo based dropdown stops working.

I have searched a lot and tried following to resolve this issue but no use

[Has anybody used Dojo and JQuery in the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106368/did-anybody-use-dojo-and-jquery-at-the-same-project)

If I use

```
$.noConflict(true);
```

jquery dropdown stops working after one click, which means on first click it opens but then is not closed and not do anything else.

all the help would highly be appreciated.

Note: This is the very first time I am using Dojo and jquery.

**EDIT:** I used closure as well something like

```
(function($) {
var jQuery = $.noconflict(true);
   var $ = jQuery;
    })(jQuery);
```

but it also didnt help.

Please tell me how to make Dojo dropdown keep working even after Jquery-dropdown clicked.

Comment: read/look about closures.

Comment: instead you can try putting your jquery stuff inside this closure.

Comment: Ok you mean I should use closure for jquery and then noConflict outside the closure or should noConflict be not used entirely?

Comment: Could you please give a code example of how you are structuring your module definitions. In particular what your dojoConfig looks like? Also which version of dojo are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps there is another question regarding how to use jquery with dojo in the same project, it gives an example of the dojoConfig and talks about how to import jquery using AMD.

[jQuery / Dojo - How do I use jQuery with Dojo toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850314/jquery-dojo-how-do-i-use-jquery-with-dojo-toolkit/13529518#13529518)