# Using jQuery widget in Dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, jquery-select2

My web app mainly uses Dojo and I'm trying to implement jQuery's select2 (https://select2.github.io/). I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106368/has-anybody-used-dojo-and-jquery-in-the-same-project) and I know that it's possible to mix the two together but in my case, everything's built on top of Dojo and it's already a rather large web app. So is it still possible to implement a single jQuery widget into my Dojo based web app?

If not, would I have to go through the source code for select2 and convert into Dojo form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't work. As long as there aren't any conflicts, you can use other libraries in conjunction with dojo. Now it may not be built with the AMD like everything else in dojo but it will still work fine.